# Measure fields and area using google maps api in react native

Tags: react-native, google-maps, geolocation, gps, measurement

I want to implement a feature in my react native application to let the user measure area or fields with two different methods the first is manual like manually drawing the fields area in the map and secondly automatically by using the gps and entering points while he walk around the field .
Could please anyone share some resosurces or any help material that may assist me in achieving this feature.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is totally doable. Since you didn't mention any particular library, let me explain using react-native-maps (it is an awesome package :). Let's first discuss using the drawing (not sure if you literally mean drawing - at least I don't think you need to add complexity in this).

1. You can provide the `<MapView>` component provided by the package with a onTap method, when the user taps, you can add the coordinate a list of coordinates like this:

   const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

then in the map, you can do

```
<MapView onPress={(coords) => setCoordinates([...coordinates, coords])} ...rest of the code
```

2. when the user is done, you can use a bit of mathematics (https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html) or even a polygon package to calculate the area (https://www.npmjs.com/package/polygon).

Well, the second use case is easier I think as no extra interaction is needed since user can input the coordinates which you can again put in the coordinates array and use to calculate area.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your response and help much appreciated , the secind approach which I discussed in my question is preferable by the client , the client needs to activate location and start walking around the field and while he's walking he would press a button that adds a marker and then combine all the long latt and calculate the area

Comment: Perfect then, the above mentioned approach works with whichever you prefer to go with. You just need to get the location of the user when he clicks the button and append to the list. It'll work perfectly. (PS. If you got a better idea, please do let me know I'd also love to learn about any alternate approaches).